Dying Pachysandra
The pachysandra on one side of my front yard died gradually in the past two years, but the other side (last photo) is OK. I have an irrigation system, and water everywhere regularly. I live in Long Island, NY. I'm not sure about the reason, may be fungus. I'd like to know the cause and how to fix it. Thank you very much.
I also checked a few landscapers, but they are not sure about the reason, either. They suggest I try this, that, and something else if not work. They seem to be lack of the knowledge. Is the any company specialized in the plant diagnosis? Thank you.







Good side without problem.


Long Island is hardly a desert climate, so "I water everywhere regularly" is more likely to be too much than remotely needed, most of the time.

Good side has sun, bad side is shaded.
Cut some trees or transition to a more shade-tolerant ground-cover where shaded.
Pachysandra should not need irrigation in your climate, at least after initial planting and establishment of roots.

I thought that Pachysandra was a shade plant and the reason it yellows is because of too much sun.
